# Is there any snippet or jQuery plugin to list all the elements in DOM matched by easylist.txt patterns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I there,

Is there any snippet or jQuery plugin to list all the elements in DOM matched by easylist.txt or fanboy's list?

I need to remove matched elements, I know I can get the source code from AdBlock Plus, but I checked it out, and I get confused with the rest of the app, since its all written in JS but with browser-specific events and functions since it's ment to be integrated as an extension.

I've found some selector component but I dont know how to implement it.

[Take a look at EasyList's filters](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)

I need a function that would give me the matched elements in a list/array so I can process the thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some thinking about which attributes to look in but i guess the "Attribute Contains Selector" will help.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: The problem is I get the expressions from easylist.txt so It's kind of tricky, I know It is possible because AdBlock Plus is written in JS, but the files are like "3 gazzillion" lines each, and it's difficult to tell where it calls it